# Need to know if transit visa is required to change the flight in US

Tags: visas

Hi I am travelling from india to canada
I have a vaild canada visa 
The flight which i booked layover in newyork for 5hrs 
Should I take a transit visa ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes because you legally enter the USA when you get off the plane and a Canada Visa is not a US visa.

Comment: You've been here long enough to know that a one-line answer with no references or information gets auto-flagged as low quality ;)  Want to perhaps expand on your answer?

Comment: I figured the question would be closed shortly, so didn't take time to create an encyclopedic answer, simply answered the query "should I".

Comment: You could just do what the rest of us do and mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - From my point of view, this question is point specific whereas the "duplicate" is rather generic, so I didn't vote it as duplicate, but figured others would.  So I gave a simple and direct answer to help the OP.  I answer questions to help people, the rest of you can be the police and gather your bounties.

Comment: +1 so as to offset the negative score, but I agree with Mark that we should always try to do the very best we can.